# Erro ao rodar Spring Roo

Tags: java, java-ee, spring

Estou tentando instalar e rodar o Spring Roo. Baixei ele, descompactei na pasta opt, dei as permissões na pasta e criei os links.

Porém ao rodar o comando "roo" um erro grande aparece e trava o programa tendo que fechar o terminal.

Segue o erro:

```
2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 69.0: missing    requirement [69.0] package; (package=javax.xml.namespace)]]]]]]] at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundle(Felix.java:3564)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1797)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1192)
at org.apache.felix.framework.StartLevelImpl.run(StartLevelImpl.java:266) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
ERROR: Bundle org.springframework.roo.addon.web.mvc.controller [49] Error  rable)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 19.0: missing requirement [19.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.roo.classpath)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 53.0: missing requirement [53.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.roo.file.monitor)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 56.0: missing requirement [56.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.roo.support.util)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 69.0: missing requirement [69.0] package; (package=javax.xml.namespace)]]]]]])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.springframework.roo.addon.web.mvc.controller [49]: Unable to resolve 49.0: missing requirement [49.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.roo.addon.finder)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 25.0: missing requirement [25.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.roo.addon.jpa.activerecord)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 30.0: missing requirement [30.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.roo.addon.configurable)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 19.0: missing requirement [19.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.roo.classpath)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 53.0: missing requirement [53.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.roo.file.monitor)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 56.0: missing requirement [56.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.roo.support.util)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 69.0: missing requirement [69.0] package; (package=javax.xml.namespace)]]]]]]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundle(Felix.java:3564)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1797)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1192)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.StartLevelImpl.run(StartLevelImpl.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
ERROR: Bundle org.springframework.roo.addon.web.mvc.embedded [50] Error starting file:/opt/spring-roo-1.2.5.RELEASE/bundle/org.springframework.roo.addon.web.mvc.embedded-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.springframework.roo.addon.web.mvc.embedded [50]: Unable to resolve 50.0: missing requirement [50.0] package; (package=javax.xml.parsers))
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.springframework.roo.addon.web.mvc.embedded [50]: Unable to resolve 50.0: missing requirement [50.0] package; (package=javax.xml.parsers)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundle(Felix.java:3564)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1797)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1192)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.StartLevelImpl.run(StartLevelImpl.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
ERROR: Bundle org.springframework.roo.addon.web.mvc.jsp [51] Error starting file:/opt/spring-roo-1.2.5.RELEASE/bundle/org.springframework.roo.addon.web.mvc.jsp-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.springframework.roo.addon.web.mvc.jsp [51]: Unable to resolve 51.0: missing requirement [51.0] package; (package=javax.xml.parsers))
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.springframework.roo.addon.web.mvc.jsp [51]: Unable to resolve 51.0: missing requirement [51.0] package; (package=javax.xml.parsers)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundle(Felix.java:3564)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1797)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1192)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.StartLevelImpl.run(StartLevelImpl.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
ERROR: Bundle org.springframework.roo.addon.web.selenium [52] Error starting file:/opt/spring-roo-1.2.5.RELEASE/bundle/org.springframework.roo.addon.web.selenium-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.springframework.roo.addon.web.selenium [52]: Unable to resolve 52.0: missing requirement [52.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.roo.addon.web.mvc.controller.details)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 49.0: missing requirement [49.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.roo.addon.finder)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 25.0: missing requirement [25.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.roo.addon.jpa.activerecord)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 30.0: missing requirement [30.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.roo.addon.configurable)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 19.0: missing requirement [19.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.roo.classpath)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 53.0: missing requirement [53.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.roo.file.monitor)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 56.0: missing requirement [56.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.roo.support.util)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 69.0: missing requirement [69.0] package; (package=javax.xml.namespace)]]]]]]])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.springframework.roo.addon.web.selenium [52]: Unable to resolve 52.0: missing requirement [52.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.roo.addon.web.mvc.controller.details)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 49.0: missing requirement [49.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.roo.addon.finder)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 25.0: missing requirement [25.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.roo.addon.jpa.activerecord)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 30.0: missing requirement [30.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.roo.addon.configurable)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 19.0: missing requirement [19.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.roo.classpath)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 53.0: missing requirement [53.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.roo.file.monitor)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 56.0: missing requirement [56.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.roo.support.util)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 69.0: missing requirement [69.0] package; (package=javax.xml.namespace)]]]]]]]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundle(Felix.java:3564)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1797)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1192)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.StartLevelImpl.run(StartLevelImpl.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

---

Coloquei somente uma parte pequena pois o código é muito grande. Ele fala algo sobre missing requirements (falta de requerimentos). O que seria?

O Java e o Maven estão instalados corretamente. Uso Linux Mint 17 cinnamon 64-bit.

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo log você provavelmente esbarrou nesse Bug: [[ROO-3505]](https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO-3505). Por enquanto o Spring Roo é incompatível com o Java 8, instale uma versão do JDK 7 e tenha certeza que você está rodando o Spring Roo com ele.